# Tikz Externalize with Title Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I have written a [thesis class](https://ctan.org/pkg/thesis-gwu) that is also available on [Github](https://github.com/skulumani/thesis-gwu). I am using this for my thesis and want to include several Tikz/PGFPlots.

**When using the externalize library, the autogenerated figures include the title page and frontmatter in them, rather than just the tikz figure.**

My original thought was that my document class was set to automatically include the frontmatter regardless of the options and that tikz was going to just use the class to create the image, however it now seems that tikzexternalize uses the options from the main document. Which causes the front matter to be included in the figures.

[This](https://github.com/skulumani/thesis-gwu/blob/tikz/thesis-sample.tex) works as expected

```
\documentclass[thesis]{./thesis-gwu}[2018/05/21]
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {x^2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Externalized}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However if I include the front matter (a title page) it no longer works

```
\documentclass[thesis]{./thesis-gwu}[2018/05/21]
\showtitlepage
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {x^2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Externalized}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I've created a branch [here](https://github.com/skulumani/thesis-gwu/tree/tikz) to try and debug this but am having no luck.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Welcome! Conditionalise the inclusion of the extra stuff? Or optmise relevant commands away?

Comment: Since you are the author of the class, can you make a minimal version we can use to reproduce the issue? It sounds as if you've figured out which bits are responsible already. But, basically, you're obviously going to have a `\begin{document}` when the image is externalised, so you don't want this adding stuff. Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` and `cleveref` too early. As you've configured it, there's a problem if users want to add packages in the preamble and there's a problem even if they don't for `hyperref`.

Comment: Also, you are adding spurious spaces at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has e.g.

```
\AtBeginDocument{ %
  \titlepage %
  ...
}
```

You instead need something like

```
\AtBeginDocument{% do not add spurious space!
  \tikzifexternalizing{}{\titlepage}%
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could 'optimise away' the relevant commands e.g.

```
\tikzset{%
    external/optimize command away=\titlepage{0},%
}
```

This could obviously be done in either the document or the class file.

Incidentally, you want something like

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
    <code loading hyperref>
    <code loading cleveref>
}
```

so that people can load other packages in their preambles.

## EDIT

If you go with the class route, you need to make sure that `tikzifexternalizing` is defined. However, you don't really want to require people to use `tikz` if they don't need it otherwise. So you could do something like this:

```
\AtBeginDocument{% do not add spurious space!
  \providecommand\tikzifexternalizing[2]{#2}%
  \tikzifexternalizing{}{\titlepage}%
  ...
}
```

If the command is already defined, this will make no difference. If not, it will just use the second argument i.e. `\titlepage`, which is what you want. Since you can't load packages or libraries after `\begin{document}`, this allows people to use `tikz` `external` or not, without having to force the loading of this code on everyone who uses the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments. I'll give it a shot and report back.

I also appreciate the advice on helping to improve the the class file. It's a big help.

Comment: The `\tikzifexternalizing{}{}` conditional seems to be working great.

Comment: @shanksk It should! But, if you put it in the class file, you will need to make sure it is defined.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did discover that almost immediately. Now everyone who ends up using this class file will also be using tikz! I think it'll take a little longer for me to figure out the correct ordering of hyperref/cleveref/glossaries but I appreciate the advice. Incidentally, is there a more appropriate place to get some advice on the LaTeX package?

Comment: @shanksk You could just make `\providecommand\tikzifexternalising[2]{#2}` as the first thing in `\AtBeginDocument`. Then you don't need to load `tikz`.

Comment: @shanksk I don't really know anywhere, sorry. There's the code review SE site, but I'm not sure it is much use for LaTeX. You could try asking in chat.

Comment: @shanksk Also edited into answer above. Ti*k*Z is a lot of code, so it is best not to make people load it unless you really need it for some special effect. :-)